# Azure Data Factory: Start of SSIS-Integration Runtime takes very long time

Tags: ssis, azure-data-factory

Our problem is that Start / Stop of the Integration Runtime takes 4 to 6 minutes!
When checking the screenshot in the docs post below the start process takes 3 seconds.

What can be the cause of the poor performance?

We are evaluating the SSIS runtime in Azure datafactory. The integration runtime (IR) is quite costly and we want to keep costs down by starting and stopping the IR.
There are several blogs on how to achieve this including the Microsoft docs one:
https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/azure/data-factory/how-to-schedule-azure-ssis-integration-runtime#test-run-your-pipelines

```bsh
# Example in powershell

Write-Output (Get-Date)
Stop-AzDataFactoryV2IntegrationRuntime -Name XXXXXXIntegrationRuntime -ResourceGroupName XXXXXX -DataFactoryName XXXXXXDataFactory
Write-Output (Get-Date)

#result
Wednesday, 18 September 2019 08:20:33
Wednesday, 18 September 2019 08:24:54
```

Answer (score 1):

That command just sends the order to stop the IR, but it doesn't wait until it is actually stopped. Try using Get-AzDataFactoryV2IntegrationRuntime and check the status.

You are not doing anything wrong with the IR, it takes like 5-10 mins to start and stop (stop is usually faster in my experience). As far as I know, there is no way to make it start or stop faster, so you should build your scripts to check the status periodically and wait for the IR to be up and running.

Hope this helped!